# Flutter : DateTime.now().toIso8601String() Math

Tags: flutter, dart

i have DateTime.now().toIso8601String() = `2022-08-09T03:01:32.223255`

how can i find if 3 days have passed since the date ?

Comment: Do you still have the DateTime value, or do you need to work from the string?

Comment: yes i have DateTime value

Comment: So subtract the "then" time from the "now" time, which gives you a Duration object, which can be queried for number of days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse string to `DateTime` object:

```
final dateTime = DateTime.now();
final stringDateTime = dateTime.toIso8601String();
final parsedDateTime = DateTime.parse(stringDateTime);
```

In this case, dateTime and parseDateTime are the same.
Then to find out the time difference use `difference` DateTime instance method, which returns Duration instance. Example from dart documentation:

```
final berlinWallFell = DateTime.utc(1989, DateTime.november, 9);
final dDay = DateTime.utc(1944, DateTime.june, 6);

final difference = berlinWallFell.difference(dDay);
print(difference.inDays); // 16592
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the difference function on DateTime object:

```
  DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  DateTime addedThreeDays = DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 3));
  
  print(3 >= now.difference(addedThreeDays).abs().inDays);
```